# What is the meaning of (0.0) in C++

Tags: c++, syntax

I want to know what this line of code means:

```
GL gl_abc;  // GL is global struct type...

...

if (some condition is true)
{
    gl_abc = (GL)(0.0);
}
```

What does `(GL)(0.0)` mean in C++?

Comment: Does the `GL` struct have any constructors?

Comment: It appears to be a C-style cast of the `double` constant 0.0 to a `GL` object/value/structure. Or a strangely-parenthesized `GL` object constructor call with a single `double` argument.

Comment: Cody Gray .. No, there isnt any constructor declared, but as it is already answered and if I take 0.0 as constructor then it makes sense.

Comment: If it doesn't have any constructors, then you shouldn't be able to construct with a double literal. Rakibul's answer assumes that it has some compatible constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gl_abc = (GL)(0.0);` means an object of type `GL` is being created, using `0.0` as constructor parameter, and  `gl_abc` is being **assigned** to the newly created object using *assignment* operator.

What may confuse you is the extra parenthesis around `GL`, but it s redundant, and `gl_abc = GL(0.0);` would have similar effect.